# Printing float with chosen length in julia

Tags: julia

When I save my data files, I have a parameter that it is a float, which I want to keep it as a float in the filename. I don't have round up errors, because I define the values of the parameter using

```
parameters = zeros(Float64, 1000)##50)
iijj = 4.8999
for jjj in 1:1000
    iijj += 1/10000
    iijj = round(iijj, 4)
    parameters[jjj] = iijj
end
```

and thus every `parameter[i]` is a float with just `4`decimals.
My issue comes when printing the files, I am using

```
printfile = open("outfile_param$(param).dat" ,"w")
```

where `param=parameters[i]`. If I have for example `4.89`, I would like to have the name `outfile_param4.8900.dat`, instead of `outfile_param4.89.dat`.

I know there are several ways to write in an outputfile, but I would like to keep the format that I have because if not it would be a pain to correct the programs that I work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`@sprintf`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Printf/#Printf.@sprintf) to have more precise control over the formatting:

```
julia> @sprintf("outfile_param%.4f.dat", 4.89)
"outfile_param4.8900.dat"
```